# What is the reason humans need to die and why do the aliens think the scientists will do this?

Tags: alien-invasion, the-27th-day

I just saw *The 27th Day* on YouTube and watched the scene where "The Alien" explains the situation. As I understand it:

1. The Alien's race will be destroyed by a supernova -- they therefore need a new planet.
2. They want Earth but their moral code prevents them from directly killing any intelligent life
3. He gives them each a weapon which as I understand will kill only humans within a 3,000-mile radius; in concert, the devices would kill every human.

My questions are:

1. Why do the aliens need this to happen -- maybe because Earth lacks enough resources for both races, maybe because humans start wars that would destroy now both human and alien if they relocated; could it be that humans are in some other way unhealthy or objectionable to the aliens?
2. Why do the aliens think the humans will voluntarily use the weapons against their fellow humans and what if not all of them do?

I am not sure the plot is logically consistent -- what am I missing?

Comment: Isn't it just a basic "look at how petty and self-destructive humans are" plot?  The whole bit about the aliens is just a framing device to hang the plot on.

Comment: where is the venality aspect? don't that word mean something like "greedy"?

Comment: I mistyped; I meant "venial" not "venal," but "petty" is much clearer.

Comment: @releseabe  It has been decades since I saw The 27th Day (1957)  but if I remember correctly there was a revelation about the aliens's motives at the end.  So I have to wonder whether releseabe saw the whole movie or maybe saw some remake of it with a somewhat different plot.

Comment: @M.A.Golding: I am talking about understanding the alien's explanation to the humans at the beginning, whether that speech covers things or not because it seems to me the scientists to whom the devices were given could simply toss them in the ocean as indeed of them does.

Comment: As for 2, at the time of the movie there was already a policy of "Instant retaliation", later renamed to Mutual Assured Destruction. If politicians and strategists on earth found it possible that mankind would eradicate itself, then why shouldn't aliens? So basically you are missing some good old Cold War paranoia (which is a good thing IMO).

Answer (score 2):

First, it is left ambiguous as to whether The Alien needs the entirety of Earth to settle his people, or just a part of it. As he notes, the use of all of the capsules could indeed eradicate all of humanity, but the implication is that every government has the opportunity to instead eradicate up to three enemy nations. He states that he believes that this will lead to humanity's utter destruction, given our prior proclivities, but he does not outright state that that is the goal.

As noted by M.A. Golding, the ending does have a twist.

> The capsules only affect people opposed to peace, so even when they are set off, they only kill warmongers, "enemies of human freedom". In addition, the remaining human race bands together to offer the doomed alien race the ample unused space on Earth, which seems to ultimately be what leads to the alien confederation welcoming Earth among its ranks.

Setting aside the ending revelation, The Alien states why they believe the weapons will be used in his speech, "Your entire history is one of self-destruction." Essentially, he states that alien observation has shown that humanity will extinguish itself by its very nature, and by providing a weapon that will only kill humans, they will save the planet for their use, as the human weapons, such as the "H Bomb" called out in his speech as humanity's current ultimate weapon, will poison the planet beyond use. And while I don't think The Alien believes that these five people themselves will doom humanity, he sets things up so that they can turn the weapons over to their government, who can use the weapons, which means the decision to use the capsules can go to the lowest common denominator.

Comment: why not tell these scientists the truth? very contrived aliens but we don't know how contrived aliens will be.

Comment: Truthfully, I think that their elimination of the warmongers was intentional, and they were truthful about their aversion to killing directly (or simply feared the reaction of humanity if they showed up, zapped a portion of humanity claiming they were "the bad guys", and then started negotiations).